# GET the content of an <option> in a <select> instead of the value

Tags: php, html, select

I have the following HTML select FORM:

```
<select name="quantity">
        <option value="0" >Select</option>
        <option value="125" >1</option>
        <option value="250" >2</option>
        <option value="375">3</option>
        </select>
```

I know how to GET the value of each option above but is there any way to GET the variable (1,2.3...)

Comment: Nope, you should set them in the value option eg `<option value="1">1</option>`

Comment: If those values don't come from some data structure on the server, no; the browser will send the value from the selected `<option>` element, not its text.

Comment: You need JavaScript for this.

Comment: to get the text you can make use of jQuery ajax..

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a decent question.

Comment: Please formulate a decent title for your question, especially if you want people who could answer it to pay attention.

Comment: @BartFriederichs my best guess is that the downvote was because of the title "please help i am noob php" is not a valid question.

Comment: @IesusSonesson that's why I changed it :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<select name="quantity" onchange="javacript: var valor = this.options[selectedIndex].text;  alert(valor); document.getElementById('shadow').value = valor;">
    <option value="0" >Select</option>
    <option value="125" >1</option>
    <option value="250" >2</option>
    <option value="375">3</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="shadow" value="">
```

With this combination you can accomplish your task.....javascript + hidden input, and php $_GET['shadow'] ;)

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Under normal circumstances, when a form is submitted, only the value(s) of the selected item(s) in a select element will be submitted. The label will not.

Your options:

- Keep a map of values/labels on the server and use the submitted value to retrieve the label
- Store the label in the value (possibly by encoding the existing value and the label as JSON)
- Use JavaScript to add the label to the submitted data

I strongly suggest the first option.

Answer (score 1):

If you put in a hidden field called SelectedHTML you can achieve this with javascript.

```
<input type="hidden" id="SelectedHTML" name="SelectedHTML" />
```

for example with an onchange event on the select to put the innerHTML of the selectedIndex into the hidden field, when posted you will be able to use $_GET['SelectedHTML'] to retreive the data

```
<select onchange="document.getElementById("SelectedHTML").value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;" name=....>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, not in standard HTML.

You could use JavaScript to do it somehow.

Answer (score -2):

You can't do that with PHP. You need javascript (jQuery).

Method text()

```
  $('option').text();
```

would return that for you and then you can send it with GET with window.location

```
  window.location = 'yoururl.php?value=' + $('option').text();
```

Comment: I never said he must use jQuery.

Comment: let me quote you "You can't do that with PHP. You need javascript (jQuery)." if hes learning, dont suggest jquery.

Comment: jQuery would be optional. It's possible to use jQuery for a task without understanding javascript fully.

Comment: It's possible to open people without knowledge of medicine too